# Having trouble toggling class

Tags: javascript, sass, haml, codepen

So my goal is to have the ability to be able to toggle the input with the custom checkbox I created. Right now I have it working, however, it only adds the class to the first child (option 1)

See image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClIDq.png)

When I click the option 2 and three the default checkbox still shows up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOa3s.png)

I've tried using document.querySelectorAll and that does not work.

Here is a link to the Codepen codepen.io/Brushel/pen/QqLgyZ

Here is the code:

```js
checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox')

checkbox.addEventListener 'click', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  document.querySelector('input').classList.toggle 'checkmark'
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: seagreen;
  --secondary-color: white;
}

body {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.checkmark {
  display: inline-block;
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 6px;
      height: 12px;
      border: solid seagreen;
      border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
%body
  %ul
    %li
      %input#checkbox(type="checkbox")/
      %label(for="checkbox") Option 1
    %li
      %input#checkbox(type="checkbox")/
      %label(for="checkbox") Option 2
    %li
      %input#checkbox(type="checkbox")/
      %label(for="checkbox") Option 3
```

Comment: ids are singular, you can not have more than one element with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, an Id is a unique `Id`entifier, you want to apply a class to your checkboxes or select them by their type or some other similar method useful for selecting multiple ([`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll))

```
 const checkboxHandler = checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      checkbox.classList.toggle('checkmark');
    })
 };

 let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')
 checkboxes.forEach(checkboxHandler);
```

- Select all checkboxes by your delimiter
- Iterate over checkboxes
- In each iteration you will apply a click handler
- Inside the click handler is where you set your required actions.